# Are these two representations equivalent? $\ln(x)$ in powers of $x-4$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

I was considering the rather simple problem of expressing $\ln(x)$ in powers of $x-4$. I know how this is done, so my question is not about the solution. Rather, I was considering an alternative step in the way I traditionally go about problems such as this, and found I got a different answer. But to my eyes both approaches should be equivalent!

Approach $a$: Let $u=x-4$ so that $\ln(x)=\ln(u+4)=\ln(4(1+\frac{u}{4}) = \ln(4)+\ln(1+\frac{u}{4})$. Because $\frac{d}{du}\ln(1+\frac{u}{4})=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+\frac{u}{4}}= \frac{1}{4}\sum(-1)^n (\frac{u}{4})^n$ we have

$$\ln(x)=\ln(4) + \int \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-4)^n}{4^{n+1}}$$
$$=\ln(4) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-4)^n}{n4^{n}} dx + C$$

Approach $b$): The alternative is to begin with the same steps as before, letting $u = x-4$, and then notice that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{u+4} = \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+\frac{u}{4}}$. We expand this as a series and integrate (as we did in previous step) and we have

$$ \ln(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(x-4)^n}{n4^{n}} + C$$

So the same series without the starting term $\ln(4)$.

This may mean that the second procedure is wrong somewhere, though I fail to see where. Or perhaps it simply means that both representations differ in the constant $C$ resulting out of the integration and are equally valid?

Comment: Yes, it's the usual issue, those aren't the same constant. Also once you integrate you shouldn't have a $dx$ in there anymore.

Comment: Oh, the $dx$ was a copy-pasting typo. Thanks for pointing it out. So both solutions are correct, then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you don't need integration at all. Even if you want to use it by setting $x=4$ you get $C=0$. So there is no constant in the first case.

In the second case setting $x=4$ you get $C=ln4$. So the results coincide!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You are welcome!